# Display sql database for chrome history file

Tags: python, google-chrome, sqlite, pycharm

I'm attempting to display my chrome history in a separate window. I don't receive an error but nothing is displayed. Here is my code.

```
import sqlite3
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\Lewis Collins\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History')
conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
output_file = open('chrome_history.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
headers = ('Title', 'Visit Count', 'Date (GMT)')
csv_writer.writerow(headers)
epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
for row in (c.execute('select url, title, visit_count, last_visit_time from urls')):
    row = list(row)
    url_time = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=row[3])
    row[3] = url_time
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

I did get the code base from another article and I am trying to expand on it for my own program. Why isn't the Pycharm script displaying any tables?

Answer (score 1):

Unclear if you want these rows to show up in your console or elsewhere, but right now you have this set up to write to a file via because of these two lines:

```
output_file = open('chrome_history.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
```

The 'chrome_history.csv' is specifying the target file that you are writing your csvs to. I ran your code locally and it wrote to the .csv just fine, so you might just need to open up that csv (it'll be in the same directory as the python script is saved.)

If I'm misunderstanding and you want this data to appear in your console and use csv, you'd need to import sys and then specify your target as 'sys.stdout' like this:

```
import sys
...
csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
```

This is a bit of a roundabout since using 'print' will get you the same result without having to create a csv.writer object.  Example:

```
print(header)
...
for row in (c.execute('select url, title, visit_count, last_visit_time from urls')):
    ...
    print(row)
```

My best guess is that you're doing it right but you don't know where the output is, since printing to the console would be pretty unwieldy.  With that in mind, I've tweaked your code and added in a bit at the end to open up the file afterwards (assuming you're working on windows - mac users have a few more steps, see this link: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/04/python-101-how-to-open-a-file-or-program/)

```
import csv
import os
import sqlite3

from datetime import datetime, timedelta


with sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\Lewis Collins\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History') as conn:
    conn.text_factory = str
    c = conn.cursor()
    output_file_path = 'chrome_history.csv'
    with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        headers = ['URL', 'Title', 'Visit Count', 'Date (GMT)']
        csv_writer.writerow(headers)
        epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
        for row in (c.execute('select url, title, visit_count, last_visit_time from urls')):
            row = list(row)
            url_time = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=row[3])
            row[3] = url_time
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
os.startfile(output_file_path)
```

A few notes:
Added in 'with's for your open connection statements.  With automatically closes these connections and provides error handling.  See link for details: http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/

Added an extra item to your headers variable, since you're pulling 4 items in your SQL statement.

Added 'quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL' that will fully quote all of your rows - should be helpful when looking at URLs or page titles that might have spaces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help i appreciate it, what I was wanting to do is have it so that when i attach that script to a button it opens the resulting data in a new window/Frame where the data would be presented under headers, but i'm lost in how to do this

Comment: Got it - I'd suggest updating your original question to specify the exact location that you'd like your output to appear and exactly what environment that you're working with.  You have your data in a usable format, so the more specific you are about where you want the output to go the better folks will be able to help.